# sublime-hooks plugin - multiple commands on event hook

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I use [sublime-hooks](https://github.com/twolfson/sublime-hooks) plugin to run a sublime command on event hook. I usually use it to run only one command on event hook. I don't know how to run multiple commands on one event hook. I tried this, but it does not work.

**CSS.sublime-settings**

```
    {
    "on_pre_save_language": [
        {
            "command": [
                "autoprefixer",
                "css_comb"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [plugin docs](https://github.com/twolfson/sublime-hooks) given in the provided link:

> Hooks are stored in the User, Project, or Language settings. **Each of
>   these expects a list of dictionaries**. Each of those dictionaries
>   satisfies the following:
>
> - *command* [...]
> - *args* [...]
> - *scope* [...]
> - *views* [...]

So don't make an array of commands but add an object (with command/args) to the array for every command:

```
{
    "on_pre_save_language": [
        {
            "command": "autoprefixer"
        },
        {
            "command": "css_comb"
        }
    ]
}
```